# App crashes when when back button is pressed (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I am programming an android app in Android Studio using a thread in a fragment to graph 100 random values, but when the back button is pressed before all the values are graphed the app crashes.

Can somebody tell me how can I stop the thread when the back button is pressed.

```
public class fragment_Usuario_Mediciones extends Fragment{
//variables para grafica
private static final Random RANDOM= new Random();
private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
private int x = 0;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usuario_mediciones,container,false);

    //instancia del GraphView
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphView);


    //datos
    series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    graph.addSeries(series);



    Viewport viewport = graph.getViewport();
    viewport.setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    viewport.setMinX(0);
    viewport.setMaxX(100);
    viewport.setScrollable(true);


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Simulacion en tiempo real con hilo
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //añade 100 nuevas entradas


            for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AniadirEntrada();
                    }
                });
                //consumir pulsos de reloj
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //manejar el error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }).start();
}


private void AniadirEntrada()
{
    series.appendData(new DataPoint(x++,RANDOM.nextDouble()*10d),true,100);
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
    //    getActivity().finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

}

Comment: show your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a new **handler** and runnable:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do what ever you want
    }
};
```

To start execution use - `handler.post(runnable);`

Remove your callback from your handler in **onpause or onstop** overridden method:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Or

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

In the docs for removeCallbacksAndMessages it says...

> Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent messages whose obj is
>   token. If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data using AsyncTask like this:

```
private class fetchData extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // your code here
         return someValue;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         // update the UI here
     }
 }
```

Further, you can enhance the whole code using callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

In your android manifest declare your earlier activity as parent activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.Detail"
        android:label="Detail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.xyz.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```